# Как заставить JUnit выводить все ошибки?

Tags: java, junit

Сейчас, при выполнении любого юнит-теста, Junit выводит только первую попавшуюся ошибку (если зафейлился assert). Как настроить аггрегирование ошибок, чтобы во время выполнения они накапливались, а потом в самом конце выбрасывались разом?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду агрегацию ассертов **в одном тесте**, то это физически и морально невозможно. Физически - потому что там бросается исключение, морально - потому что код после первого сломавшегося утверждения уже скорее всего неверен, т.к. оперирует недостоверными данными.

Comment: @Etki Это нужно для понимания общей картины: тест, который зафейлился полностью, и тест с небольшой помаркой - выдают одну и ту же информацию разработчику, что может сильно запутать.

Comment: В тестах не существует "небольшой помарки", там исключительно булева логика "работает согласно спецификации или нет". Если у вас слишком большой тест, то это отдельный вопрос.

Comment: @Etki ага, у нас интеграционные тесты на Junit работают и 20 раз запускать каждый проблемный, получая ошибки порционно - вариант плохой.

Comment: если отвечать коротко, то вам а) нужен [Allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/) ([steps](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/Steps)) и б) запретить коллегам писать тесты более чем на одну фичу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class AssertsAccumulator {
    private boolean assertsPassed;

    private StringBuilder errors;

    /**
     * Initializes a new instance of the class.
     * <pre>
     * {@code AssertsAccumulator assertsAccumulator = new AssertsAccumulator();
     *   assertsAccumulator.accumulate(() -> assertNotNull(null));
     *   assertsAccumulator.release();
     * } </pre>
     * @see AssertsAccumulator
     */
    public AssertsAccumulator() {
        this.errors = new StringBuilder();
        this.assertsPassed = true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets Regularly updates progress on a given task.
     * Should be invoked every time task.ProgressValue or task.MaxProgressValue changes
     */
    public String getAccumulatedErrorMessage() {
        return this.errors.toString();
    }

    /**
     * value indicating whether assert passed or failed.
     * @return <c>true</c> if assert passed, <c>false</c> otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isAssertsPassed() {
        return assertsPassed;
    }

    /**
     * Regularly updates progress on a given task.
     * Should be invoked every time task.ProgressValue or task.MaxProgressValue changes
     */
    public void release() {
        if (!this.assertsPassed) {
            throw new AssertionError(this.getAccumulatedErrorMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * updates progress on a given task.
     * be invoked every time task.ProgressValue or task.MaxProgressValue changes
     *
     * @param action Action for run
     */
    public void accumulate(Runnable action) {
        try {
            action.run();
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            this.registerError(e);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            this.registerError(exception);
        }
    }


    public void accumulate(Runnable action, String key) {
        try {
            action.run();
        } catch (AssertionError e) {
            this.registerError(
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            this.registerError(exception);


        }
    }
    /**
     * Regularly updates progress on a given task.
     * Should be invoked every time task.ProgressValue or task.MaxProgressValue changes
     */
    private void registerError(Throwable e) {
        this.assertsPassed = false;
        this.errors.append(e.getMessage() + "\n" + stackTraceToString(e));
        this.errors.append(Messages.getLineSeperator("~", 40));
        this.errors.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    private String stackTraceToString(Throwable e) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int k = 0;
        for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace()) {
            sb.append(element.toString());
            sb.append("\n");
            if (k > 5) break;
            k++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

использовать так

```
AssertsAccumulator accumulator = new AssertsAccumulator();
accumulator.accumulate(() -> Assert.fail()));
accumulator.accumulate(() -> Assert.fail("Message")));
accumulator.release();
```

Comment: В Intellij Idea информативный вывод comparison result'а будет работать для каждой ошибки, случайно не знаете?

Comment: немного не понял вопроса. не могли бы уточнить ?

Comment: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Files do not match:
 C:\...\actual_file
 C:\...\expected_file
  <Click to see difference> при нажатии по Click to see difference IDEA показывает side-by-side окно, в котором можно увидеть конкретное место расхождения.

Comment: нет, так как `ComparisonFailure` наследуется от `AssertionError`,который ловится в `catch`. так что будет пойман в `AssertsAccumulator`

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!